# Regular expression for postscript code

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for this.

I need it to grab the 9 digit number that's in brackets provided a '6 /Helvetica-Bold f' has appeared before it but not a '6 /Helvetica f'

```
6 /Helvetica-Bold f
6 /Helvetica
<-- any number of lines of other text -->
261 632 m(436243874)r 1 9 0 Endline    <--- this would not match
6 /Helvetica-Bold f
<-- any number of lines of other text -->
261 632 m(436243874)r 1 9 0 Endline    <--- this would match
```

I found that this - "6 /Helvetica-Bold[\s\S]+((\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d))" was no good as it would match for both cases as shown above.
Can anyone help it's driving me nuts?

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: And: Is the 9-digit number always in the line following the one with `6/Helvetica-Bold f`?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that there could be any other amount of text between the 'Helvetica-Bold' line and the line with the number I need.  I am doing this in AutoIT which uses the same semantics as Perl.

Comment: There can also be lines between '6 /Helvetica-Bold f' and '6 /Helvetica'

Comment: The example you want to match does not fulfill your criteria (starts with 10 instead of 6). Which is the correct rule?

Comment: Sorry, I must have gone a bit nuts with copy and paste.  I have updated the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
6\s*/Helvetica-Bold f(?:(?!6\s*/Helvetica)[\s\S])+\((\d{9})\)
```

should work. <sub>(Re-edited to fit to edited example)</sub>

**Explanation:**

```
6\s*/Helvetica-Bold f     # match 6 /Helvetica-Bold f
(?:                       # match the following as many times as possible
 (?!6\s*/Helvetica)       # (as long as it's not possible to match 6 /Helvetica here
 [\s\S]                   # match any character
)+                        # at least once
\(                        # match a literal (
(\d{9})                   # match and capture 9 digits
\)                        # match a literal )
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I think that's because it expects the 'Helvetica f' to be on the next line from 'Helvetica-Bold'